# MVC In PHP Framework

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

i saw this diagram which represent what i've been coding for laravel php framework. [image]

However, i was told by some other developers that  for MVC, the model can update the View directly   as shown in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller.

Is there a sub-type of MVC or laravel is implementing a different type of MVC? I've used Laravel and codeignitor before and they both seems to work like the first diagram.

Comment: This is a [fine article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/) about MVC. Actually there are many ways to approach this architecture pattern, and it's more up to your needs and project modeling than anything (for instance, Router isn't really an 'official MVC part' [if there is any], as it acts as a general request controller, but even though that approach is still valid MVC)

Comment: Nor Laravel nor CodeIgniter implement that classical MVC. They call "modified" version of it. If you modify a view from a model (as its described in the paper), that will introduce a number of another issues for web. That's why all major frameworks don't implement it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many variation of MVC, pattern, e.g.:

- [Model-View-Presenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter)
- [Model-View-ViewModel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)

It's not just "plain" MVC known from SmallTalk, but a variation of it.